# C - Initializing a hash table

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I'm learning about structures and hash tables and I'm trying to figure out how to put everything together. I want to be able to add words to the hash table and then every time that word is added a second time, it increments a counter instead of adding that word again. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599

struct NodeType
{
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct NodeType *next;
};
typedef struct NodeType Node;

unsigned int hash(const char *str);
Node **ht_create(void);

int htsize;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Please declare a table size");
        return 1;
    }
    htsize = atoi(argv[1]);
}

unsigned int hash(const char *str)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int h = OU;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        h = h * HASH_MULTIPLIER + (unsigned char) str[i];

    return h % htsize;
}

Node **ht_create(void)
{

}
```

So here is where I'm stuck. If I want to dynamically allocate a hash table of size `htsize`, do I just initialize an array using malloc? I'm really lost here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your hash table is likely defined as an array of pointers.  Each entry in the array points to the beginning of a linked list of words that hash to the same value.  So, you'd use malloc or calloc to create your array of pointers.  Initially, they'd all be NULL since the hash table starts out empty.

Comment: so that would look something like `char **Table = malloc(htsize);`?

Comment: close.  You need to do something like struct NodeType* Table = malloc(htsize * sizeof (struct NodeType *));  htsize needs to be multiplied by that size of a pointer.